# Looking for tips for Integration Testing of a Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration-testing

I am working on a Java EE 6 application that consists of multiple components, which are all packaged as separate Maven projects:

- `MyAppInterface` - OSGi module, contains entity classes, including JPA and JAX-B annotations
- `MyAppRealm` - OSGi module, contains custom Glassfish LoginModule and Realm
- `MyAppServer` - web application, contains EJBs, EntityFacades, JAX-RS Gateway, a few administrative JSPs
- `MyAppWeb` - web application, GWT app, communicates with MyAppServer via XML/REST

The reason why they are all separated in different projects is for scalability reasons - not everything is deployed everywhere. `MyAppInterface` is used by all other projects. Everything is running on Glassfish 3.1.

Now I'd like to introduce the concept of integration testing to this. Leaving out `MyAppWeb` for a moment, I'm thinking it'd be ideal to test everything via the JAX-RS gateway.

How would you do this?

Obviously the whole stack needs to be "assembled" before tests can be executed, including backends (database, email MTA). Should I even try to do this automatically? Jenkins builds everything (but does not deploy it automatically).

Here are my thoughts: Since each of the components by itself is not "complete", I'm thinking there is no point placing the tests in any of the projects. Instead I'm considering adding a component `MyAppIntegrationTest` with nothing but tests in it, with Jersey Client and `MyAppInterface` as dependencies. In order to test, I would build all components, deploy them on a test glassfish, then pass the URL to `MyAppIntegrationTest` and let it run its tests.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've no direct Java EE 6 experience.

However, as a point of reference, in Eclipse plug-in development, it is quite common to have separate projects / plug-ins / bundles for (integration) testing.

Thus, using a separate `MyAppIntegrationTest` component to take care of the integration testing makes perfect sense to me.